# Fluent NHibernate Inheritance Base Class

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a Base Class called User. Teacher and Student derive from User class. There is a table called Users.

Users have some common properties which will be used by Teacher and Student classes. The User class mapping looks something like this:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).ColumnName("UserId");
            WithTable("Users");
        }
    }
```

Now, for some reason when I save the Teacher it says FirstName cannot be null. But I am assigning the FirstName

So, basically the question is how to map the base class to a table whose subclasses are also using the same table.

Comment: Actually it turns out that I can use it I just have to define the Mappings for the subclasses same as the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into using the [DiscriminatorSubClassesOnColumn](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/05/fluent-nhibernate-subclass-syntax-changes/) method.